# How can I test keydown events in Jasmine with specific keyCode on Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular5, karma-runner

In my application I have an `<input>` field on which I want to trigger keydown events.

### My Setup

- Karma v1.7.1 test runner
- Chrome browser running the tests
- Angular 5

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution. I created a function that can be called passing the key code as parameter:

```
function keyDown(key: number) {
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).triggerEventHandler('keydown', { key: key });
}
```